# Why cannot Google JSON library properly serialize this HashMap?

Tags: java, json, gson

I have two HashMaps to be serialised to JSON using Google Gson library:

```
    final Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>() {
        {
            put("abc", "def");
        }
    };

    final Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map2.put("abc", "def");

    final Gson gson = new Gson();
    final String s1 = gson.toJson(map1); // "null"
    final String s2 = gson.toJson(map2); // {"abc":"def"}
```

Why is the second HashMap correctly serialized but not the first HashMap?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gson uses reflection and doesn't care whether or not a class implements `Serializable`. Gson does, however, need a no-arg constructor (see the [design doc](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-design-document)):

> Gson needs to create a dummy class instance before it can deserialize
>   Json data into its fields ... we create class instances by invoking the
>   parameterless constructor ...

When you call `toJson(Object obj)` Gson will use `obj.getClass()` to figure out how to construct a "dummy instance" of `obj` which in your case is an anonymous **inner** class. Inner classes require a reference to their containing class in order to be constructed. The reference to the outer class is not available at the time of serialization which is why your result is `null`. You can get around this issue by providing Gson with a little more information about how to construct your object:

```
final Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>() {
  {
    put("abc", "def");
  }
};
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(map1, new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>() {}.getType()); // {"abc":"def"}
```

**Edit:** Note that this only works because your anonymous class can be cast to `Map<String, String>`. If you had a more complex inner class such as:

```
final Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>() {
  private String additionalData = "Foo";

  {
    put("abc", "def");
  }
};
```

`additionalData` would not be in the output.